# entity framework object with sub-object save sub-object once

Tags: c#, entity-framework

### edit: made a little mistake in description

i have class User which has property of class Group

```
class User {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Group Group {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Group {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

now i'm creating a list of User class which some of them might contain same class Group value

example data:

```
var users = new List<User> {
    new User {
        Name = "user1",
        Group = getGroup("admin2",..moreParams)
    },
    new User {
        Name = "user2",
        Group = getGroup("admin2",..moreParams)
    },
    new User {
        Name = "admin1",
        Group = getGroup("admin2",..moreParams)
    },
    new User {
        Name = "admin2",
        Group = getGroup("admin2",..moreParams)
    },
};

public Group getGroup(params){
    if(_cacheGroups.Any(someRule)){
        return _cacheGroups.First(someRule);
    }else{
        ... loading the correct group
    }
}
```

how do i prevent the entity framework from saving the group multiple times

currently exception message is

> Duplicate entry 'users' for key 'IX_Name'

Comment: maybe create one reference of Group? `Group users = new Group { Name= "users" }` and use this for both user1 and user2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `Group` for each `User`, some of them has the same `Name`, that causes the error(The `Name` has unique Index). You must create one instance for each distinct `Group` and then assign the `Group` of each `User` based on them:

```
var admins =  new Group {
            Name= "admins",
        };
var users = new Group {
            Name= "users",
        };
var users = new List<User> {
    new User {
        Name = "user1",
        Group = users
    },
    new User {
        Name = "user2",
        Group = users
    },
    new User {
        Name = "admin1",
        Group = admins
    },
    new User {
        Name = "admin2",
        Group = admins
    },
};
```